# Rails Migration Create Table Primary Key

Tags: mysql, optimization, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I am writing a migration script to create a table with a primary key column that is named `guid` and is a `VARCHAR(25)`. The issue is I feel like I am having to double my effort to achieve what should be possible in one step.

If I run:

```
create_table(:global_feeds, :primary_key => 'guid') do |t|
  t.string :guid, :limit => 25
  t.text :title
  t.text :subtitle

  ...

  t.timestamps
end
```

I get a table with a primary key called `guid` no column called `id` (which is what I want). However, the issue is the `guid` column is an `INT(11)` with auto increment turned on. So I have to run one additional command:

```
change_column :global_feeds, :guid, :string, :limit => 25
```

Seems a bit convoluted to have to basically run two SQL commands to get what I believe should be possible in one.

Any suggestions on how to optimize this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suppose you're using mySQL, so here is what you can try

```
create_table :global_feeds, {:id => false} do |t|
  t.string :guid
  t.text :title
  t.text :subtitle
  t.timestamps
end
execute "ALTER TABLE global_feeds ADD PRIMARY KEY (guid);"
```

If you're not on mySQL you should change the query in the `execute` command to work on your DB engine. I'm not sure if you can do that on SQLite though. And don't forget to put this line somewhere in global_feed.rb model:

```
set_primary_key :guid
```

Anyway you're getting the most out of Rails while you're sticking to its conventions. Changing primary key name and type might not be a very good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still two SQL statements like mine. You have just flipped the order of operations: you are defining the column type first and then specifying the primary key.

Comment: I guess you can't do that in one operation, but i guess there is nothing wrong with it. It's perfectly ok for the migration to have two statements for a bit more complex cases.

Comment: Also i'm not sure if ActiveRecord works fine with non integer primary keys at all.

Comment: I am going to vote you up just for the effort maxt3r. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I ran into this issue dealing with an schema I inherited; I tried pretty much all possible combinations using `primary_key` and most of the other suggestions in this and other related questions.  On Rails 3.2.x with MySQL this solution was the one that worked.  A key issue to be aware of: `rake db:schema:dump` will not result in the needed output (`db:structure:dump` is ok).  Echoing @MaxAlFarakh's comments: changing primary key name and type, not a good idea :-|

Answer (score 29):

In Rails 4 you can do;

```
create_table :global_feeds, id: false do |t|
  t.string :guid, primary_key: true
 ...
end
```

Comment: this should not be a string, mysql with uuid should be a binary(16)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use #column instead of #string. For instance:

```
create_table(:global_feeds, :primary_key => 'guid') do |t|
  t.column :guid, "varchar(25)", :null => false
  ...
end
```

Note that the `varchar` type is not portable to databases other than MySQL.

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
      t.column :guid, :varchar(26), :null => false` With it pointing to the parenthesis at the end of varchar

Comment: Right you are. Use `"varchar(25)"` instead of `:varchar(25)`.

Comment: You could have also just used the `:string` type and set `limit: 25` as an option for this example.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in Rails 3. try:

```
  def self.up
    create_table(:signups, :id => false) do |t|
      t.string :token, :primary => true
```

check out this gist for a great solution for using UUIDs as a primary key col: https://gist.github.com/937739

Comment: See answer by @kakoni

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5, for thoes who got problem `ArgumentError: Index name '*' on table '*' already exists` when `rails db:setup` with migration as from @kakoni, the following works for me

```
create_table(:global_feeds, primary_key: :guid, id: false) do |t|
  t.string :guid
 ...
end
```

For more information, check [create_table](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table).