# Using guids for all model ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guid

What would it take, in a new rails application, to use GUID's instead of integers for id's in my models?

Are there any 'gotchas' when doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769725/rails-migration-create-table-primary-key

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I'm using mysql.

Answer (score 3):

There's a gem for that!: https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid

Your migrations look like:

```
create_table :user do |t|
  t.uuid :id, :primary_key => true
end
```

And you model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveUUID::UUID
end
```

All code above taken/inspired from the [readme](https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid)

Comment: but are there any gotcha's with that?